# Tab Corrupted in Win32 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tabs, win32gui

My application (C++, Visual Studio 2015) incorporates tab control. In most cases it behaves well.
Rarely, changing a tab results in corrupted interface.

**Example**:

Tab 1:

[image: Tab 1]

Tab 2:

[image]

Sometimes, when moving from Tab 1 to Tab 2 I get:

[image]
The arrow points on the problem area.

My code is very simple:
     All tabs are implemented as dialog boxes
     When the user click on a tab, all dialog boxes are hidden (ShowWindow)
     Then the selected tad shows its dialog box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is cause by group box, it's background is not erased. Remove `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag from the parent of group box (child dialog or child window which owns the group box). Or subclass the group box control to paint its background.